# Hardhat deploys contract to 2 different contract addresses while deploying uniswap clone

Tags: hardhat, uniswap, testing, chai

I am learning about writing tests with Hard Hat and using fixtures, but I am having the strangest issue when deploying a uniswap clone. My deployWETH fixture consistently returns the same contract address, but for some reason my deployUniswapFactory fixture is getting 2 different addresses? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
// fixtures

async function deployFactoryFixture() {
  const { uniswapDeployer, uniswapDeployerAddress } =
    await establishWalletsFixture();

  // Deploy the factory
  const UniswapV2Factory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    'UniswapV2Factory',
    { signer: uniswapDeployer }
  );
  const uniswapV2Factory = await UniswapV2Factory.deploy(
    uniswapDeployerAddress
  );
  await uniswapV2Factory.deployed();
  const factoryAddress = await uniswapV2Factory.address;

  console.log(
    `deployFactoryFixture: UniswapV2Factory Address ${factoryAddress}`
  );

  const initHash = await uniswapV2Factory.INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH();

  return {
    UniswapV2Factory,
    uniswapV2Factory,
    factoryAddress,
  };
}

async function deployRouterFixture() {
  const { uniswapDeployer } = await establishWalletsFixture();
  const { wKAVAAddress } = await deployWKAVAFixture();
  const { factoryAddress } = await deployFactoryFixture();

  // deploy the router
  const UniswapV2Router02 = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    'UniswapV2Router02',
    { signer: uniswapDeployer }
  );
  const uniswapV2Router02 = await UniswapV2Router02.deploy(
    factoryAddress,
    wKAVAAddress
  );
  await uniswapV2Router02.deployed();
  const routerAddress = await uniswapV2Router02.address;
  console.log(
    `deployRouterFixture: UniswapV2Router Address ${routerAddress}`
  );
  console.log(
    `deployRouterFixture: UniswapV2Factory Address ${factoryAddress}`
  );

  return { UniswapV2Router02, uniswapV2Router02, routerAddress };
}

// describes

describe('UniswapV2Factory Deployment', function () {
  it('Should have fee setter to contract deployer', async function () {
    const { uniswapDeployerAddress } = await loadFixture(
      establishWalletsFixture
    );
    const { uniswapV2Factory } = await loadFixture(deployFactoryFixture);

    expect(await uniswapV2Factory.feeToSetter()).to.equal(
      uniswapDeployerAddress
    );
  });
});

describe('UniswapV2Router02 Deployment', function () {
  it('Should have factory set to factory address', async function () {
    const { factoryAddress } = await loadFixture(deployFactoryFixture);
    const { uniswapV2Router02 } = await loadFixture(deployRouterFixture);

    expect(await uniswapV2Router02.factory()).to.equal(factoryAddress);
  });
});
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
  KBTEST Full Coverage
    Establish Wallets
      ✔ Should establish a list of signers/wallets (1549ms)
    WKAVA Contract Deployment
      ✔ Should have a contract address (126ms)
    UniswapV2Factory Deployment
deployFactoryFixture: UniswapV2Factory Address 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
      ✔ Should have fee setter to contract deployer (127ms)
    UniswapV2Router02 Deployment
deployFactoryFixture: UniswapV2Factory Address 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512
deployRouterFixture: UniswapV2Router Address 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0
deployRouterFixture: UniswapV2Factory Address 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512
      1) Should have factory set to factory address
    IterableMapping Contract Deployment
deployIterableMappingFixture: IterableMapping Address 0x8464135c8F25Da09e49BC8782676a84730C318bC
      ✔ Should have a contract address


  4 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) KBTEST Full Coverage
       UniswapV2Router02 Deployment
         Should have factory set to factory address:

      AssertionError: expected '0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3…' to equal '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f641…'
      + expected - actual

      -0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512
      +0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
      
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/kbtest.js:232:52)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that cares about this problem in the future, I found a solution by combining my factory and router contract deployments into a single fixture. whether this is how it should be done or not is something I don't have the answer to, but below are the steps I took...

```
async function deployUniswap() {
  const { uniswapDeployer, uniswapDeployerAddress } =
    await establishWalletsFixture();
  const { wKAVAAddress } = await deployWKAVAFixture();

  // Deploy the factory
  const UniswapV2Factory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    'UniswapV2Factory',
    { signer: uniswapDeployer }
  );

  const uniswapV2Factory = await UniswapV2Factory.deploy(
    uniswapDeployerAddress
  );

  await uniswapV2Factory.deployed();
  const factoryAddress = await uniswapV2Factory.address;
  console.log(`UniswapV2Factory Address ${factoryAddress}`);

  // deploy the router
  const UniswapV2Router02 = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    'UniswapV2Router02',
    { signer: uniswapDeployer }
  );
  const uniswapV2Router02 = await UniswapV2Router02.deploy(
    factoryAddress,
    wKAVAAddress
  );

  await uniswapV2Router02.deployed();
  const routerAddress = await uniswapV2Router02.address;
  console.log(`UniswapV2Router Address ${routerAddress}`);

  return {
    UniswapV2Factory,
    uniswapV2Factory,
    factoryAddress,
    UniswapV2Router02,
    uniswapV2Router02,
    routerAddress,
  };
}

describe('Uniswap Deployment', function () {
  describe('Factory Deployment', function () {
    it('Should have fee setter to contract deployer', async function () {
      const { uniswapDeployerAddress } = await loadFixture(
        establishWalletsFixture
      );
      const { uniswapV2Factory } = await loadFixture(deployUniswap);

      expect(await uniswapV2Factory.feeToSetter()).to.equal(
        uniswapDeployerAddress
      );
    });
  });

  describe('Router Deployment', function () {
    it('Should have factory address set to factory contract', async function () {
      const { uniswapV2Router02, factoryAddress } = await loadFixture(
        deployUniswap
      );

      expect(await uniswapV2Router02.factory()).to.equal(factoryAddress);
    });
  });
});
```

and the test results:

```
  KBTEST Deployment
    Uniswap Deployment
      Factory Deployment
wKAVA Address 0x8464135c8F25Da09e49BC8782676a84730C318bC
UniswapV2Factory Address 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
UniswapV2Router Address 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512
        ✔ Should have fee setter to contract deployer (984ms)
      Router Deployment
        ✔ Should have factory address set to factory contract
```